# search folder for subfolders containing certain string, exclude lagging values

Tags: python, string, search

How do i search a string in python for a value and only return if the string does not contain any leading/lagging values from the search string. white spacing is aceptable, i.e.

I would like to search a folder with sub folders below for "WO1" or "WO1 BLD2 L1 H3 Fitout"

Subfolder:

> WO1
>   WO123
>
> SP10152100 WO137
>
> WO1 BLD2 L1 H3 Fitout

the code i am using returns "SP10152100 WO137"

```
temp_WO_dir1 = "WO" + wo
path = root + "\\"+ dir
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        print dir
        if temp_WO_dir1 in dir:
            find = True 
            sp_path = root +  "\\" + dir + "\\3 Finance\\Telstra Invoicing"
            print sp_path
            break

    if root.count(os.sep) - path.count(os.sep) == 0:
    del dirs[:]
```

**Update:**

Tried the following but not working

```
if re.match(temp_WO_dir1+"\s" , dir):
```

Comment: `if temp_WO_dir1 == dir`?

Comment: Thanks, i have revised my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WO1` flanked by a word boundry, proceeded by anything, followed by anything.

`.*\bWO1\b.*`